# Ruby naming question

Tags: ruby

I'm puzzled why File::CREAT is named that way. Why CREAT and not CREATE? TRUNC is ok. WRONLY, sure fine. but CREAT...

It seems ruby has weird name shortening scheme (which is readable, but usually is not intuitive) that is found in method names too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of `creat()` is a sort of historical wart. When [Kenneth Thompson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Thompson) was asked what he'd do if given the chance to go back and do *one* thing differently when designing UNIX, he famously answered "I'd spell `creat()` with an e".

So, no good reason really. :)

Answer (score 5):

Probably based on [open(2)](http://docsrv.sco.com/cgi-bin/man/man?open+2)'s flags.